# Skydrive rename folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, onedrive

I am using Skydrive gem in my rails application.

For renaming the folder I had written

```
def renaming_folder
  client = Skydrive::Client.new(@@access_token)
  folder_id = params[:folder_id]
  # (url, {:body => options})
  # options = {name: "#{params[:rename_field]}"}
  puts "-------------------..."
  puts "#{params[:folder_id]}"
  client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id)

  # I believe issue comes from this line:
  folderObject = client.update_skydrive_object("#{params[:folder_id]}", options={name: "#{params[:rename_field]}"})

  redirect_to drive_show_path
end
```

But I am getting http_error_400: Bad Request error.  I am getting

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"BAYGFcb5/74c7RV5NH1u4DCAT1MqLvLCkp9F3Q/Fav+B2wdab4aE5LBJAVr90MMu0GbfFwHTuLyncFRWtGyYTA==",
 "rename_field"=>"weqweqwe",
 "folder_id"=>"folder.cecb8eb83d90dbeb.CECB8EB83D90DBEB!106",
 "commit"=>"Rename Folder"}
```

in my parameters.

Can some please help? Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

I am able to get all the values when I add puts.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 400 error means the server could not understand your HTTP request: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/400error.htm.

`"#{params[:folder_id]}"` and `"#{params[:rename_field]}"` are unnecessary ways to just say `params[:folder_id]` and `params[:rename_field]`, which are already strings.

Do `client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id).update(options={name: params[:rename_field]`.

Your solution should be:

`skydrive_folder = client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id)
skydrive_folder.update(options = {name: params[:rename_field]})`

For reference: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/skydrive/1.2.0/Skydrive/Operations#update_skydrive_object-instance_method
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/skydrive/Skydrive/Folder#update-instance_method

Source code:

Line 119: https://github.com/ronyv89/skydrive/blob/master/lib/skydrive/operations.rb

Line 44: https://github.com/ronyv89/skydrive/blob/master/lib/skydrive/client.rb

Comment: Changed skydrive_object = client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id) skydrive_object.update_skydrive_object(params[:folder_id], options={name: params[:rename_field]}) but its giving NoMethodError: undefined method `update_skydrive_object' for #<Skydrive::Folder:0x007fe73e729f48> error

Comment: Also checked for blank values in option folderObject = client.update_skydrive_object("#{params[:folder_id]}", options={}) then its giving Skydrive::Error (http_error_400: Bad Request)

Comment: If you have any other option then please let me know.

Comment: What class is client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id)? What does  client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id).class say?

Comment: The result of client.get_skydrive_object_by_id(folder_id).class is => Skydrive::Folder

Comment: Skydrive::Folder has an "update" method: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/skydrive/Skydrive/Folder#update-instance_method. I've changed my answer above. Does my new answer work?

Comment: I had already checked with update method. But it was also giving the same issue.

Comment: What error message did you get? Did you replace your 2 lines exactly with my 2 lines?

Comment: I am getting the same error Skydrive::Error (http_error_400: Bad Request)